# Subscript out of bounds - Loading .gpx file

Tags: r, gpx

At this moment I am experimenting with reading GPX files, so far I have exported runs from my sports tracker app and I have managed to load these correctly and plotted them on a map.

Now I have drawn a new route in my app and exported this into a .gpx file, however when I try loading this in R I get the following error:

> Error in nm[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

**R code :**

```
library(plotKML)
library(leaflet)
route <- readGPX("../GPS data Serge/Testing.gpx", tracks = TRUE)
```

**Testing.gpx file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Endomondo.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata>
    <author>
      <name>Wouter Baeckelmans</name>
    </author>
    <link href="http://www.endomondo.com">
      <text>Endomondo</text>
    </link>
    <time>2015-12-02T15:53:31Z</time>
  </metadata>
  <trk>
    <name>Test</name>
    <src>http://www.endomondo.com/</src>
    <link href="https://www.endomondo.com/routes/639589549">
      <text>Test</text>
    </link>
    <type>RUNNING</type>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="8.39087" lon="-12.94756"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.39022" lon="-12.94777"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.38974" lon="-12.94861"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.38307" lon="-12.94227"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.38248" lon="-12.94181"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.3822" lon="-12.94171"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.38104" lon="-12.94155"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.3765" lon="-12.94101"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.37593" lon="-12.94086"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.37556" lon="-12.94065"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.37522" lon="-12.9404"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.3742" lon="-12.93948"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.37367" lon="-12.93893"/>
      <trkpt lat="8.37305" lon="-12.93819"/>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

Any idea's on what could be causing this? I noticed this .gpx files looks different than the other .gpx file that I could load succesfully. That file contained a `trkseg` tag for each `trkpt` tag...
But I think it should be possible to load this file as well, I just don't seem to find how.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please see [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Complete data and (for those that don't know that you're probably using the `plotKML` package) minimal working code would help. I don't see how we can help w/o the full data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried `readOGR` from the `rgdal` package?

```
> route = readOGR("Testing.gpx","tracks")
OGR data source with driver: GPX 
Source: "Testing.gpx", layer: "tracks"
with 1 features
It has 12 fields
> plot(route)
```

and there it is.

`route` is now a `SpatialLinesDataFrame`, so read up on the `sp` package to understand what you can do with it. `SpatialLinesDataFrame` features can be complex things, such as entire branching river systems, so access to the raw coordinates can be correspondingly complex. If you know your data is a simple single line, then you can get the coordinates as a 2-column matrix:

```
> coordinates(route)[[1]][[1]]
           [,1]    [,2]
 [1,] -12.94756 8.39087
 [2,] -12.94777 8.39022
 [3,] -12.94861 8.38974
 [4,] -12.94227 8.38307
 [5,] -12.94181 8.38248
 [6,] -12.94171 8.38220
 [7,] -12.94155 8.38104
 [8,] -12.94101 8.37650
 [9,] -12.94086 8.37593
[10,] -12.94065 8.37556
[11,] -12.94040 8.37522
[12,] -12.93948 8.37420
[13,] -12.93893 8.37367
[14,] -12.93819 8.37305
```

This is because you have one feature and one line in that feature.

Looking at the `readGPX` code I suspect a bug in its handling of names in the GPX file....

Comment: Thanks, I managed to load the file like this and plot it! Do you have any idea on how to extract the latitude & longitude coördinates out of the route object? Nevermind, seemed like fortify from the ggplot2 package worked... Thanks for your help!